# Get node logs from docplex

Tags: cplex, docplex

CPLEX prints out [nice node logs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/para/52_node_log.html), how can I get them using docplex? I've tried changing content.solver.verbose and log_output but I'm not getting the information (current solution, gap) to print.

I'm using this code:

```
context.solver.log_output = True
context.solver.verbose = 5
mdl = CpoModel()
mdl.solve()
```

With verbose = 5, all of the branch decisions are printed (lots of junk)
With verbose = 4, the gap is not printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the code in the question and filtering output with grep.

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
model = build_model()
model.context.solver.log_output = True
model.solve()
```

If this does not work for you, can you please provide some sample code so that we can have a look at it ?
Thanks

Comment: I have added code, now the issue is that I can't just print out the gap